# Mysql not returning result when using escaped slash using match statements

Tags: php, mysql, match, full-text-search

I have a record where `firstname` equals `\`. For some reason, its not returning me the record.

```
SELECT 
    firstname,lastname,middlename,
    primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
    personal_address_line2,personal_address_city,facebook_username,
    twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
    personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes,personal_address_zipcode,
    company_address_zipcode,home_phonenumber,company_phonenumber,
    cell_phonenumber,birthday_day,birthday_year,hash 
FROM contacts 
WHERE (
        MATCH( firstname,middlename,lastname,
            primary_emailaddress,alternate_emailaddress,personal_address_line1,
            personal_address_line2,personal_address_city,facebook_username,
            twitter_username,googleplus_username,linkedin_username,
            personal_website_url,birthday_month,notes ) AGAINST ('\\*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        OR personal_address_zipcode REGEXP('(\\*)') 
        OR company_address_zipcode REGEXP('(\\*)') 
        OR home_phonenumber REGEXP('(\\*)') 
        OR company_phonenumber REGEXP('(\\*)') 
        OR cell_phonenumber REGEXP('(\\*)') 
        OR birthday_day REGEXP('(\\*)') 
        OR birthday_year REGEXP('(\\*)') 
    ) 
AND addressbook_id = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that very short words are not indexed, by default.  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) is the documentation:

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by
>   the ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len system variables. (See Section
>   5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.) The default minimum value is four characters; the default maximum is version dependent. If you change
>   either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For example, if
>   you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the
>   ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option
>   file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

This applies to boolean search as well as natural language.  You will need to change the option an rebuild the index.

Alternatively, you could put in a `regexp` expression for `firstname`:

```
    OR firstname REGEXP('(\\*)')
```

Comment: when you say an option file, you mean php.ini?

Comment: @jkushner . . . No.  This is the option file for MySQL.  You can read about it here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html.

Comment: @jkushner . . . I do not know.  To some extent it depends on your data.

Comment: I added the ft_min_word_len to my.cnf and it did not seem to work.

Comment: @jkushner . . . Did you rebuild the index?

Comment: yep. i tried \ and it did not work. im going to try "joe", which is a 3 letter name

Comment: joe did not work. i know your answer is right, because i can search against 4 letter words, however it doesnt seem to be working. Im using amazon ec2. maybe i should be altering a different file? maybe my.cnf isnt getting loaded

Comment: @jkushner . . . Can ou switch to just using the `regexp` form instead?

Comment: unfortunately no. i tried that and it caused a huge performance issue.